# WebBrowser cuts off DocumentText

Tags: c#, browser, html-agility-pack

I have a simple (and weird) problem. When I manually set the `WebBrowser.DocumentText` property to some HTML string, it cuts it off after a random character. The HTML I use is the plain HTML of some other page, downloaded via HtmlAgilityPack (in real application I do some processing over it, but even without any processing the bug is present). When I load the same page in Internet Explorer, the entire page is rendered correctly.

Here's the minimal example:

```
const string url = "http://www.zip-codes.com/county/IL-COOK.asp";
var doc = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);

HtmlNode basehref = new HtmlNode(HtmlNodeType.Element, doc, 0) { Name = "base" };
basehref.Attributes.Add("href", url.Substring(0, url.LastIndexOf("/") + 1));
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//head").ChildNodes.Insert(0, basehref);

string html;
using (var writer = new StringWriter()) {
    doc.Save(writer);
    html = writer.ToString();
}

var thread = new Thread(() => {
    var browser = new WebBrowser {
        Location = new Point(0, 0),
        Size = new Size(1920, 1080),
        ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true,
        AllowNavigation = true,
        DocumentText = html
    };
    browser.DocumentCompleted += (sender, e) => {
        Console.WriteLine(html.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(browser.DocumentText.Length);
        Application.ExitThread();
    };
    Application.Run();
});
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
thread.Join();
```

It outputs:

```
35259
20477
```

Comment: Analyze the web page's DOM with FireBug, IE's or Chrome's debuggers (F12). Maybe HtmlAgilityPack doesn't run some JavaScript or scrupulous content similarly as a "real" browser, which is needed for full display. Do you know what Web Client technology HtmlAgilityPack uses under the hood and how?

Comment: @CsabaToth HtmlAgilityPack just sends a general `HttpWebRequest`. Anyway, this is not the source of the problem. Note that (a) HtmlAgilityPack`s string is _longer_ than the WebBrowser's string, and (b) the string is cut off in the middle of the text, after a random character. It is not a valid HTML with missing tags. It is a prefix of the original string (which IE tried to fix as much as it could and somehow rendered partially).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried your code without `Application.ExitThread()` and as it turns, `DocumentCompleted` gets fired twice, the second time the length looks being correct. Thus, the website your're trying to load probably has some dynamic content or is refreshing itself. I haven't dug into what it does, but rather went ahead and removed all scripts, styles and iframes:

```
    const string url = "http://www.zip-codes.com/county/IL-COOK.asp";
    var doc = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);

    doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                    .Where(n => n.Name == "script" || n.Name == "style" || n.Name == "iframe")
                    .ToList()
                    .ForEach(n => n.Remove());
```

Now `DocumentCompleted` gets fired once, and the document length is consistent.

Comment: @user3061212, sorry not sure I got your question

Comment: if you use new HtmlWeb().Load(url); you have the web page but it doesn t exec the javascript, instead of WebBrowser

Comment: @user3061212, indeed. Html Agility Pack doesn't execute JavaScript, but [here's how you can possibly do this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18811062/1768303).

Answer (score 0):

i solved in this way:

```
const string url = "http://www.zip-codes.com/county/IL-COOK.asp";
var doc = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);

HtmlNode basehref = new HtmlNode(HtmlNodeType.Element, doc, 0) { Name = "base" };
basehref.Attributes.Add("href", url.Substring(0, url.LastIndexOf("/") + 1));
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//head").ChildNodes.Insert(0, basehref);

string html;
using (var writer = new StringWriter()) {
    doc.Save(writer);
    html = writer.ToString();
}

var thread = new Thread(() => {
    var browser = new WebBrowser {
        Location = new Point(0, 0),
        Size = new Size(1920, 1080),
        ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true,
        AllowNavigation = true,
        DocumentText = html
    };
    browser.DocumentCompleted += (sender, e) => {
        Console.WriteLine(html.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(browser.DocumentText.Length);
        //Application.ExitThread();

        if (browser.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
                Application.ExitThread();   // Stops the thread
        }
    };
    Application.Run();
});
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
thread.Join();
```