# Get current WebBrowser DOM as HTML

Tags: c#, html, video, xpath

I want to use the HTML ability pack on a WebBrowser that has loaded all the things I need (It clicks a button with code to load every video on the channel)
(It loads a YouTube channel, and then loads all the videos on said channel.)
Now if I try to get all the videos details (I have a working code that gets the first 30 videos of a channel into a listview) it will still show only the first 30, but I have all the videos loaded on the WebBrowser page (It shows all videos)
I am using this to get whats currently loaded from the WebBrowser

[image]

but it still only loads the first 30 videos instead of all the videos loaded from the WebBrowser .

Comment: Are you tied to the technologies you are using currently?  PhantomJS is really slick with things like this.

Comment: that will return the Html at the time the page initially loaded, not anything that was dynamically added using ajax

Comment: how do i get whats dynamically loaded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the target website uses AJAX heavily (as Youtube does), it's hard, if not impossible, to determine when the page has finished loading and executing all dynamic scripts. But you could get close by handling `window.onload` event and allowing an extra second or two for non-deterministic AJAX calls. Then call `webBrowser.Document.DomDocument.documentElement.outerHTML` via `dynamic` to get the currently rendered HTML.

Example:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DownloadAsync("http://www.example.com").ContinueWith(
        (task) => MessageBox.Show(task.Result),
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}

async Task<string> DownloadAsync(string url)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> onloadTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler handler = null;

    handler = delegate
    {
        this.webBrowser.DocumentCompleted -= handler;

        // attach to subscribe to DOM onload event
        this.webBrowser.Document.Window.AttachEventHandler("onload", delegate
        {
            // each navigation has its own TaskCompletionSource
            if (onloadTcs.Task.IsCompleted)
                return; // this should not be happening
            // signal the completion of the page loading
            onloadTcs.SetResult(true);
        });
    };

    // register DocumentCompleted handler
    this.webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += handler;

    // Navigate to url
    this.webBrowser.Navigate(url);

    // continue upon onload
    await onloadTcs.Task;

    // artificial delay for AJAX
    await Task.Delay(1000);

    // the document has been fully loaded, can access DOM here
    return ((dynamic)this.webBrowser.Document.DomDocument).documentElement.outerHTML;
}
```

**[EDITED]** Here's the final piece of code that helped to solve the OP's problem:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(((dynamic)this.webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument).documentElement.ou‌​terHTML);
```

Comment: wut.
I have a button that, after the page has loaded and AJAX calls been made via clicks, THEN it uses the page. this answer just confuses me.

Comment: Oops, I misread the part about how you load the page, sorry. Just use the last part to get the current page HTML snapshot: `((dynamic)this.webBrowser.Document.DomDocument).documentElement.outerHTML` instead of `webBrowser.DocumentText`.

Comment: And after cleaning the code of illegal characters i get this
http://i.imgur.com/58cGnZB.png

Comment: `outerHTML` returns a string, use it with `HtmlAgilityPack` like this: `doc.LoadHtml(((dynamic)this.webBrowser.Document.DomDocument).documentElement.outerHTML)`.

Comment: I get errors with this, lots apparently (not sure why)
http://i.imgur.com/4DuJozy.png

Comment: Try this: `doc.LoadHtml(((dynamic)this.webBrowser.Document.DomDocument).documentElement.ou‌​terHTML.toString())`

Comment: Now it saying excepted ')' after outerHTML D:

Comment: Got it working
I used your first code and then LoadHTML with htmlabilitypack
Ty!
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(((dynamic)this.webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument).documentElement.outerHTML);

Comment: Could you change your answer to what i sent you that worked so others notice it easier? 
:D

Comment: @toddmo, you can with `Task.ContinueWith` or, more easy, with VS 2012 targeting .NET 4.0 with `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` (the latter would give you `async/await` for .NET 4.0).